# Jenkins - Next Execution plugin - How to get details through REST API

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

In my Jenkins i have installed a new plugin to see next executions details

**Plugin:** https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Next+Executions

I can see that in Jenkins dashboard successfully but how can i access its details through REST API, like the way we do for all other stuff in Jenkins.

I am using Java to access Jenkins via REST API.

Thanks

Comment: up to now (16.6.24), it looks it is not supported, issue is raised into jenkins https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-36210

Comment: see answer, it is supported now

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED in 2016.9.20** the REST API is supported from release 1.0.12

```
<jenkinsurl>/view/<viewname>/widgets/<n>/api/json?pretty=true
```

see detail for the ticket [JENKINS-36210](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-36210)

**Below is left for reference**

Though the REST API doesn't exist, I share the html parse python code sample for reference

It use the internal lxml code to parse and generate the list of the data, key code segment here

```py
html = urllib2.urlopen(url, context=CTX).read()

# use beautifulSoup4 instead of lxml is better, but it is not default
html2 = lxml.html.fromstring(html)
div = html2.get_element_by_id("next-exec") # key id !!
result = lxml.html.tostring(div)
tree = lxml.html.fromstring(result)  # ugly, but it works
trs = tree.xpath('/html/body/div/div/table/tr')

for tr in trs:
    tds     = tr.xpath("td")
    url     = tds[0].xpath("a/@href")[0]
    jobname   = tds[0].text_content()
    datetime = tds[1].text_content()
    status.append((datetime,  jobname, url))
return status
```

see detail in https://gist.github.com/larrycai/6828c959f57105ca93239ca6aa4fc6fa